# function to_timestamp(character varying[], unknown) does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

Faced with the issue with inserting an array of object values, the method is identifying the type of the object and sets corresponding npg db type

```
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand
{
    CommandText = $"INSERT INTO table (name, value, date) VALUES (@1,@2,to_timestamp(@3, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSUS'))"
};

var paramCounter = 1;
foreach (var val in valuesToInsert)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = $"@{paramCounter}",
        NpgsqlDbType = GetTypeByObject(val.Values) | NpgsqlDbType.Array,
        Value = val.Values
    });
    paramCounter++;
}

return cmd;

NpgsqlDbType GetTypeByObject(object[] obj)
=> obj.FirstOrDefault() switch
{
    string => NpgsqlDbType.Varchar,
    int or long or bool or double or float => NpgsqlDbType.Numeric,
    _ => NpgsqlDbType.Unknown,
}
```

With this it throws the exception: `function to_timestamp(character varying[], unknown) does not exist`. Does anybody faced with the following issue?

Comment: Well, [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) there is no function `to_timestamp()` that accepts an _array_ of values

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, okay, let's go another way, if I would remove timecast functions and then I would cast values object to an array of datetime, would that work? because now I've another exception like: `column "date" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type timestamp without time zone[]`